# How to disable screen sharing

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

I have some privacy concerns and would like to know how to disable screen sharing. I have tried turning of the WiFi but was then not able to use the internet.

Answer (score 7):

Go to System Preferences > Sharing and uncheck the box to the left of "Screen Sharing"

[image]